# Pandas apply speed up suggestions

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes with time stamps that need to be matched on closest time values. My code currently is as efficient as I know how to build it.

```
def Matcher(value,frame2):
    frame2['diff'] = frame2['TIME'].apply(lambda row: abs(row - value))
    return frame2['diff'].argmin()

frame1['dex'] = frame1['TIME'].apply(lambda row: Matcher(row,frame2)
frame2['dex'] = frame2.index
frame = pd.merge(frame1,frame2,on='dex')
```

Essentially the matcher function finds the index of the closest absolute time values of a unix timestamp. Then the DataFrames are merged. With smaller dataframes this was ok, now that the dataframes are > 30,000 rows the code takes too long to run. A 31122 long frame1 matched to a 155642 frame2 took about 45 minutes to run. Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

___________ EDIT ____________________

Below is a samaple of the data. It does not provide an instance explained in the comments below, because that is relatively hard to find.

```
print frame1.head(10)
             TIME ONE
1   1498074088.26  fb
2   1498074088.28  fb
3   1498074088.30  fb
4   1498074088.32  fb
5   1498074088.34  fb
6   1498074088.36  fb
7   1498074088.38  fb
8   1498074088.40  fb
9   1498074088.42  fb
10  1498074088.44  fb


print frame2.head(10)
             TIME ONE
1   1498074088.28  20
2   1498074088.38  01
3   1498074088.48  2a
4   1498074088.58  9e
5   1498074088.68  8c
6   1498074088.78  76
7   1498074088.88  46
8   1498074088.98  51
9   1498074089.07  bd
10  1498074089.17  34
```

Comment: post some data, but look into pd.merge_asof

Comment: @TedPetrou, merge_asof does work, however according to the docs it does a "<=" search and not an absolute search to merge on. My data is extracted from gps and other logging systems where some errors occur and a ">" time value could be much closer than an "<=" time value (assuming I am interpreting that correctly).